# it is showing an error i am trying to move my images into folders with labels

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have a dataset with multiple images and a csv file with one column having the name of the images and the other having the labels. I want to put the images in label folder but I am unable to do so. It throws an error at the end.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import os
import sys

labels = pd.read_csv(r'c:\technocolab project2\img_quantity.csv')

train_dir = r'c:\technocolab project2\archive\img'
label = r'c:\technocolab project2\DR\label'
if not os.path.exists(label):
    os.mkdir(label)

for filename, class_name in labels.values:
    # Create subdirectory with `class_name`
    if not os.path.exists(label + str(class_name)):
        os.mkdir(label + str(class_name))
    src_path = os.path.join(train_dir + str(filename) + '.jpg')
    dst_path = os.path.join(label + str(class_name) + str(filename) + '.jpg')
    try:
        shutil.move(src_path, dst_path)
        print("sucessful")
    except IOError as e:
        print('Unable to copy file {} to {}'
              .format(src_path, dst_path))
    except:
        print('When try copy file {} to {}, unexpected error: {}'
              .format(src_path, dst_path, sys.exc_info()))
```

> error: unable to copy files

you can see the image of the error:

[image]

Comment: Can you print out the error `e` also?

Comment: On which os are you? (windows, linux, macOS...) Spaces in folders/path names is usually a very bad practice and should be avoided at all cost in my opinion.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `os.path.join()` if you put only one string (created using `+`). `os.path.join()` makes send when you have many items - like `os.path.join(directory, subdirector, filename)`

Comment: did you check if you really have these elements ? Maybe you created wrong paths. You should copy path and test it directly in console/terminal. And maybe you should use \ instead of /

Comment: first you could run code without `try/except` to see FULL error message - it can helps to see real problem